# Challenges Establishing 2 Way SSL communication using built in PHP SOAP Client

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to create a connection to a SOAP webservice using a .pem certificate and  list all the functions that are available for consumption. However I have not been able to make any progress.

$client->__getFunctions() returns null and I get a error "Wrong Version".

```
$pem = 'certificate.pem';
$username = 'supertester';
$password = 'testing123';
$defaultEndpoint = " https://xxx.yyy.zzz:444/app/uat/BMS";
$uri = "https://xxx.yyy.zzz:444/app/uat";

$client = new SoapClient(null,
    array(
        'local_cert'    =>  $pem,
        'login'         =>  $username,
        'password'      =>  $password,
        'location'      =>  $defaultEndpoint,
        'uri'           =>  $uri,
        'style'         =>  SOAP_RPC,
        'use'           =>  SOAP_ENCODED,
        'soap_version'  =>  SOAP_1_2,
        'authentication'=>  SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
        'ssl'           =>  array(
                                'ciphers'=> "SHA1",
                                'verify_peer' => true,
                                'allow_self_signed' => false
                            ),
        'https'         =>  array(
                                'curl_verify_ssl_peer'  => true,
                                'curl_verify_ssl_host'  => true
                            ),
        'cache_wsdl'    =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'cache_ttl'     =>  86400,
        'trace'         =>  true,
        'exceptions'    =>  true,
    )
);

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried SOAP_1_1 for the `soap_version` option parameter?

Comment: Yes, Still no joy.